# Run jquery events simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, fadeout, simultaneous

I have a jQuery quiz, and to be able to begin the quiz, you must click the 'get started' button. `Onclick`, the header text is removed and the quiz is vertically centered (all of this should happen simultaneously). However, due to my code, the header text is removed *then* the quiz is centered. How can I make them run at the same time?

Here's my faulty code:

```
  $('#get-started').click(function(){
    $('#index-banner').fadeOut(200, "swing"); 
    $('#begin-exam').delay(210).fadeOut(180, "swing");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#content').animate({top:'25%'},700).addClass('center-exam');
  }, 209);
   
  });
```

*The 'center-exam' class simply adds a position of 'absolute' to the quiz so that it can be centered vertically*

Answer (score 0):

When you chain together your .animate and your .addClass by connecting them with the '.' One runs and completes and then the other runs.  By having them in separate statements they can be, and will be, run as close to concurrently as possible.

```
$('#get-started').click(function(){
$('#index-banner').fadeOut(200, "swing"); 
$('#begin-exam').delay(210).fadeOut(180, "swing");

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#content').animate({top:'25%'},700);
    $('#content').addClass('center-exam');
 }, 209);
});
```

Comment: Care for any additional explanation to improve your answer?